# Lists of negative discriminants by class group?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, oeis, quadratic-integer-rings

Is there a handy listing of the discriminants of imaginary quadratic fields having a given ideal class group? It would be nice to use such a resource as a source of examples.

For example, we're all set for class number $4$:

- [A013658](http://oeis.org/A013658) Discriminants with class number $4$

If we want just the cyclic or the non-cyclic groups, we can intersect with these lists:

- [A227735](http://oeis.org/A227735) Discriminants with cyclic class groups of composite order
- [A227734](http://oeis.org/A227734) Discriminants with noncyclic class groups

The latter of which results in:

- [A192322](http://oeis.org/A192322) Discriminants whose class group is the Klein $4$-group, $C_2\times C_2$

So that's really convenient! But are there also pre-computed lists to distinguish, say, $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ from $C_4\times C_2$?

(The closest resource I've found is [A225365 Discriminants with non-isomorphic class groups](http://oeis.org/A225365), which is still a great source of examples, if not exhaustive.)

Comment: See https://www.lmfdb.org/intro